# Using ng-if and ng-repeat correctly

Tags: angularjs, indexing, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

I have a rudimentary understanding of AngularJS and have a couple (possibly stupid) questions about ng-if and ng-repeat.

1. If I have a ng-repeat that looks like this:

For all containers without titles, would the ng-repeat produce those containers and not show them?  Or do they simply don't exist?  The reason I ask is I've tried to replace ng-if with ng-show, but it does not produce the same outcome of "hiding" containers that do not have titles.

2. Is there a way to code a ng-if to say if the next container has no title, then do something.  I tried something like `ng-if="item.title=='' && $index+1"`, without any luck.

Any suggestions?

My data looks like this:

```
"_sections": [{ 
     "_bootstrap_cells": 6,
        "_count": 2,
        "visible": true,
        "columns": [{
            "fields": [{
                "name": "type_of_account",
                "type": "field"
            }, {
                "name": "routing_transit_number",
                "type": "field"
            }]
        }, {
            "fields": [{
                "name": "type_of_payment",
                "type": "field"
            }, {
                "name": "check_digit",
                "type": "field"
            }]
        }],
        "caption": "Direct Deposit",
        "id": "b456b9d2137ac340177c36328144b0ef"
    }, {
        "_bootstrap_cells": 12,
        "_count": 1,
        "visible": true,
        "columns": [{
            "fields": [{
                "name": "account_number",
                "type": "field"
            }, {
                "name": "account_title",
                "type": "field"
            }, {
                "name": "financial_institution_name",
                "type": "field"
            }]
        }],
        "caption": "",
        "id": ""
    }
}]
```

The first section has two columns and a bootstrap cell value of 6 for each column, the second section only has one column and a bootstrap cell of 12.  Since the second doesn't have a caption, I want it to be appended to the first section, but keep both sections' bootstrap formatting.

Comment: i think you need to use `filters` instead of ng-if to hide some results

Comment: "Since the second doesn't have a caption, I want it to be appended to the first section, but keep both sections' bootstrap formatting." I don't understand what you mean here...

Comment: well my initial thought was to just concat the objects on top of one another, but I don't think that's possible if I want to maintain the two column format for the first section and the one column format for the second.

Answer (score 2):

If `containers` is an array then it does not have a `title` property. You need to check the title on each item.

Also note that `ng-if` will not hide the content, but remove it or not insert it into the DOM. The counterpart of `ng-show` is `ng-hide`.

```js
angular.module('appModule', [])
  .controller('MyController', [function() {
    this.containers = [{
      aaa: 1,
      title: 'One'
    }, {
      aaa: 2,
      title: ''
    }, {
      aaa: 3,
      title: 'Three'
    }]

  }]);

angular.bootstrap(window.document, ['appModule'], {
  strictDi: true
});
```

```html
<div ng-controller="MyController as myCtrl">

  <div ng-repeat="item in myCtrl.containers track by $index">
    <div ng-if="item.title!=''">{{$index}}. {{item.title}}</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this is another way to implement it.. i agree with this answer.

Comment: thanks @sebastien, so it sounds like filter wont' work right?  Ideally, i would like to ng-repeat like you did above and only show those containers with titles.  However, for those containers without a title, I would like to append it to the previous container.  Is there a way to do this?  That's why I was curious whether ng-if even creates the element...

Comment: You should probably perform that logic in the controller, but it depends on what your data looks like. Can you post it in your question?